# How to Check if String contains decimal and convert to nearest Integer?

Tags: java, floating-point, integer, double

How do I check if a String contains Integer or Decimal Numbers in Java?
Further I want to round off the number to the nearest integer if it's a decimal number and then convert it back to string.

Say,I have a string called "amount" whose value can be like "23" or "33.42", In this case I would like to convert "33.42" to "33"

Below is what I tried:

```
// Assume amount String has already been declared
            try{
                Double number = Double.parseDouble(amount);
                logger.info("Double Detected");
                int integer = (int) Math.round(number);
                logger.info("Converting to String Integer");
                amount = Integer.toString(integer);

            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                logger.info("Double NOT Detected");             
            }
```

I am getting Null Pointer Exception in the above code when I am trying to parse "Double", please also let me know if there's any easier way to do this.

Comment: You need to check first that `amount` is not `null`.

Comment: That means `amount` is `null`...

Comment: @Tommy well this is Java, not perl...so.

Comment: Amount was not null

Comment: @Kayaman I was thinking amount had letters in it too, and he had to fish the numbers out. And what do you mean by your comment?

Comment: @sahibsingh yes it is...If the content of your post is accurate.

Comment: In my case there would be only numeric data (and decimal)

Comment: Either `amount` is `null`, or your NPE is being thrown somewhere else.

Comment: @brso05 does the code look fine otherwise?

Comment: @sahibsingh yes

Comment: @Tommy I guess you're not familiar with perl's style of programming. However nowhere was it said that there would be letters.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine for me...

Comment: Hmm, I guess I will just put a logger on amount and confirm if it's blank then.

Comment: @Kayaman the title confused me. But i understand it now.

Comment: Yup, the amount is blank, Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: If `amount` isn't null, then `logger` is.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize amount to something like "" so that it won't be null if your algorithm doesn't find an Integer to convert to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
amount = new BigDecimal(amount).setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString();
```

This will give you the output you are looking for.

Comment: ... unless, as was the case here, the string is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the null pointer you can do a multi-catch statement, like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String amount = "3.14159265";
    try {
        Double number = Double.parseDouble(amount);
        System.out.println("Double Detected");
        System.out.println(number);
        int integer = (int) Math.round(number);
        System.out.println("Converting to String Integer");
        System.out.println(integer);
        amount = Integer.toString(integer);

    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e1) { //catches both exceptions
        System.out.println("Double NOT Detected: ");
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
}
```

Try changing amount to `null` or letters to see how the exception is caught.

Make sure you initialize `amount` also.